# please support for use awk and regex

Tags: solaris

I have a file with `|` separator and I need to print first field `$1` and other fields, I need to print part which match the regular expression  `\[(.*?)\>`.

```
cat x.txt |nawk -F"|" '{print $1"|"match regex $2,"|" match regex $3}'
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no need for the cat command at the beginning. You can redirect the output of the file into awk, using "< x.txt" at the end of the command line. Better still, awk can take the name of the file you want to be processed as an argument. So I think you want something like this:

```
awk -F"|" '{
  printf "%s", $1;
  for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
    if (match($i, /\[(.*?)>/)) {
      printf " %s", substr($i,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  }};
  printf "\n"
}' x.txt
```

For every line in the file, this prints the first field, followed by all the regexp matches found in each of the remaining fields (if any). The output fields are separated by spaces; this can be changed by editing the leading space in the second printf command.

Comment: in first thanks a lot for your feedback but itry to run code give error this is sample for input file and output file
123|aaa[AAA]78->dfd|100
124|bbb[BBB]78->dfd|100
125|ccc[CCC]78->dfd|100
126|ddd[DDD]78->dfd|100
127|eee[EEE]78->dfd|100
128|fff[FFF]78->dfd|100

output
123|[AAA]78|100
124|[BBB]78|100

Comment: error come from match i use solaries

Comment: Hi, I've edited the code above now. I think the problem might be that you do not need to escape the ">" character, so I've removed the second "\" from your regexp. When I now run the above code against your sample file I get the following output, which I think looks correct: `123 [AAA]78-> [BBB]78-> [CCC]78-> [DDD]78-> [EEE]78-> [FFF]78->` However, I'm running GNU awk on Linux; Solaris might vary.

Comment: thank you its worked well i want to ask you about joint command  its give me i have file with 1000 record and other file with 1000 record in need to join 2 file "join -t "|" -1 1 -2 1 1.txt 2.txt" but its give me just sample (1-9) then (90-99) then (990-999) i need to know why